# Striking Handwraps and Animal Form

Tags: magic-items, pathfinder-2e, polymorph

[Handwraps of Mighty Blows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=441) increases the damage die:

> For example, +1 striking handwraps of mighty blows would give you a +1 item bonus to attack rolls with your unarmed attacks and increase the damage of your unarmed attacks **from one weapon die to two**

Most attacks you can use in [Animal Form](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=10) do 2 die of damage, except for the claw of the Bear and the Cat. So with the Handwraps, these will do 2d8 and 2d10 (agile) respectively.

It seems to be fine as this is a constant ability of the Handwraps, which is allowed by the [Polymorph](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=127) trait.

**Does this work?**

Comment: @WeirdFrog comments are not for answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### *Handwraps of Mighty Blows* Can't Modify the Attacks

> If you take on a battle form with a [polymorph](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=127) spell, the special statistics can be adjusted only by circumstance bonuses, status bonuses, and penalties.

Normally none of the statistics granted by a battle form polymorph spell like *animal form* can be adjusted outside of circumstance/status modifiers. However, many if not all such spells include an exception like this:

> - One or more unarmed melee attacks specific to the battle form you choose, which are the only attacks you can Strike with. You're trained with them. Your attack modifier is +9, and your damage bonus is +1. These attacks are Strength based (for the purpose of the enfeebled condition, for example). **If your unarmed attack bonus is higher, you can use it instead.**

So while you can't improve the attack granted like the *ape form's* 2d6 bludgeoning fist, you could improve your own unarmed attack bonus to use in place of the +9 or whatever modifier is given by the spell. If this is your only reason for getting *handwraps* it might be worthwhile to leave off the *striking* runes.